# Make button visible by js variable

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to make a button in html visible if a variable in Javascript is true

ex code: `var systemON = true;`

And if systemON is true, I want a button to be visible in html.

Comment: Yes, you can...

Comment: Okay thanks, but how?

Comment: Post your effort, code and HTML and we will show you

Comment: `document.getElementById("buttonID").style.display=systemON?"":"none"` - css: `#buttonID { display:none }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, yes..

```
if (sistemON) {
  document.getElementById("yourButtonID").style.display = "block";
}
```

now am not sure if that is what you want or you to toggle visibility each time the variable changes in your code?

Comment: I ended up to use this form of code to show and hidden my button. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I prefer using a ternary `boolean?when_true:when_false;` which is shorthand for

```
if (boolean) {
  when_true;
}
else {
  when_false;
}
```

Then assuming the statement is executed after the button is available in the DOM you can set the display like this:

```js
document.getElementById("buttonID").style.display=systemON?"‌​":"none"; // or "block":"none"
```

using CSS

```css
#buttonID { display:none }
```

---

If you want the button to still take up space on the page, use

```js
document.getElementById("buttonID").style.visibility=systemON?"‌​visible":"hidden";
```

using CSS

```css
#buttonID { visibility:hidden }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (systemON) {
  document.getElementById("button").style.display = "none";
} else {
  document.getElementById("button").style.display = "block";
}
```

should do it

Comment: If the `if`statement was used by @Avandus, then this is the answer that was first using that format.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : https://jsfiddle.net/820dzf3j/

```
var systemON = false;
var button = document.getElementById("myButton");
if(systemON) {
button.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a sample code that does what you ask:

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/n0ft12c4/)

```js
var systemON = true;

if (systemON) {
  document.getElementById("elementToShow").className = "showClass";
} else {
  document.getElementById("elementToShow").className = "hideClass";
}
```

```css
.showClass {
  display: block;
}
.hideClass {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="elementToShow" class="hideClass">
  Show me!
</div>
```

Comment: True, that's much better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var systemON = false;

// checks if it is true
if (systemON) {
  document.getElementById("button1").style.display = "block";
} 
// checks if it is false
else { 
  document.getElementById("button1").style.display = "none";
}

var systemOFF = true;

// checks if it is true
if (systemOFF) {
  document.getElementById("button2").style.display = "block";
} 
// checks if it is false
else { 
  document.getElementById("button2").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<button id="button1">Hidden</button>
<button id="button2">Displayed</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I using this code to make a button visible and hidden, when needed

HTML:

```
<div class="system" id="SystemButton">
   <p>System Runtime <span id="runtime"></span></p>
   <p>System Failures: <span id="failures"></span></p>
   <p><button id="Shutdown" onclick="systemDown(1)">Shutdown System</button></p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var systemON = true;
if(systemON == true){
    document.getElementById('systemButton').style.display = "block";
}else{
    document.getElementById('systemButton').style.display = "none";
  }
```